# Difference in Density contour plot in seaborn and plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn, contour

I plot the density plot of my data in the seaborn KDE plot and plotly plot. I got two different results of the same data. What is the reason behind this?

```
sb.kdeplot(data['ra'], data['dec'],cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=True,cbar=True)
```

And I obtained this contour plot [image]

And I use the same data in plotly contour plot as

```
fig = px.density_contour(data, x="ra", y="dec")
fig.update_traces(
contours_showlabels = True,
contours_coloring="fill",
colorbar=dict(
    title='Number Count', 
    titleside='right',
    titlefont=dict(
    size=14,
    family='Arial, sans-serif')))
fig.update_xaxes(title_text='RA')
fig.update_yaxes(title_text='DEC')
fig.update_layout(
    #yaxis=dict(range=[-1.75, 1.5]),
    height = 800,
    width =800,
    bargap = 0,
    #hovermode = 'closest',
    title_text='DENSITY PLOT',
    showlegend = True
    )
fig.show()
```

[image]

As we can see, the contour of the lower-left is in a different position. So, which one will be more accurate and what is the reason behind this?

2. My second question is that if I want to compare two datasets by doing seaborn KDE contour plot taking the same contour level/colour-bar to compare the data. How to do that? When I do plot together at one plot, it is just plotting independently the level of contour plot in the same figure. So, I am not able to compare it as one dataset contains more number than another dataset.

Here is the sample code for that

```
slice_value1=slice_red1
X1=data1['ra']
Y1=data1['dec']
Z1=data1['redshift']


X2=data2['ra']
Y2=data2['dec']
Z2=data2['redshift']



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,label='1')

k2=sb.kdeplot(X2,Y2,cmap='Reds',shade=False, shade_lowest=True,gridsize=500, cbar=True,annot = True)
k1=sb.kdeplot(X1,Y1,cmap='Blues',shade=False, shade_lowest=True,gridsize=500, cbar=True,annot = True)
ax.scatter(X2,Y2,s=0.8,color='Red')
ax.scatter(X1,Y1,s=0.8,color='blue')
ax.set_xlabel('RA')
ax.set_ylabel('DEC')
ax.set_xlim(349.5,354.3)
ax.set_ylim(-2,1.5)
```

Here the number of [data1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R89ZCJk9u82lPQeucUGCErUG59UsTc0I/view?usp=sharing) is 300 and [data2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AyC6m7_RiHOfStdY0shiSigMGpgXeunm/view?usp=sharing) is 1200. And the figure is given here.
[image]

Comment: You are putting two quite different questions into the same post. Moreover, there are no test data. That makes the post hard to answer.  About your second question, the kdeplot is normalized and doesn't really change depending on the number of data points. If one is more concentrated than the other, the kde will have higher values. Adding e.g. `levels=np.arange(0, 0.27 ,0.02)` to both would put the contour lines on the same levels.

Comment: Kindly do find the data from here data1 [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R89ZCJk9u82lPQeucUGCErUG59UsTc0I/view?usp=sharing) and data2 [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AyC6m7_RiHOfStdY0shiSigMGpgXeunm/view?usp=sharing)   @JohanC